# Diferença de resultado entre MySql 5.5 e MariaDB 5.5

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tenho uma query rodando em meu local que está instalado o `Mysql 5.5.43`, mas quando fui subir no servidor (que tem o `MariaDB 5.5.38` e fui saber somente agora) a query não retorna o mesmo resultado, e por isso gostaria de saber se alguém saberia me dizer o porque desse resultado errado e as diferenças entre esses dois bancos de dados, que apesar de serem muito parecidos, tem ai suas diferenças, ou estou errado?

Segue um exemplo da query que estou tentando rodar, lembrando que no Mysql retorna os resultados corretos e no MariaDB que esta no servidor que não:

```
SELECT DISTINCT umr.tema_id,

    (
        SELECT count(vw1.tema_id)
        FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas vw1
        WHERE ((vw1.tema_id = umr.tema_id)
        AND (vw1.unidade_id = 68)
        AND (vw1.opt_aplicavel = 1)
        AND (vw1.opt_conforme = 1)
        AND (vw1.dt_validate >= '2015-07-22'))
    ) as conforme,

    (
        SELECT count(vw2.tema_id)
        FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas vw2
        WHERE ((vw2.tema_id = umr.tema_id)
        AND (vw2.unidade_id = 68)
        AND (vw2.opt_aplicavel IS NULL))
    ) as naoAvaliado,

    (
        SELECT count(vw3.tema_id)
        FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas vw3
        WHERE ((vw3.tema_id = umr.tema_id)
        AND (vw3.unidade_id = 68)
        AND (vw3.opt_aplicavel = 1 OR vw3.opt_aplicavel IS NULL))
    ) as totalAtribuido

FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas umr
WHERE (umr.unidade_id = 68 AND (umr.opt_aplicavel = 1 OR umr.opt_aplicavel IS NULL))
```

Segue um print que tirei dos resultados rodando essa query nas duas bases e vejam a diferença entre os dois bancos, lembrando que os dados são os mesmos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue link com um dump da base de dados para poder ser feito um teste.
https://gist.github.com/marcelod/91836c31cf4bdce5eadc

Comment: Voce tem certeza que os dados estao iguais em ambos os bancos? Que engine voce esta usando no MySQL e que engine voce esta utilizando no Maria?

Comment: Tenho certeza que é a mesma base por eu ter baixado a base inteira do servidor, criei uma base nova no meu localhost e coloquei para rodar.

Comment: Qual é a diferença que está dando entre os resultados?

Comment: São os valores que não estão vindo corretos, muitos deles no MariaDB vem zerado.

Comment: Marcelo, você poderia por gentileza executar o comando `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas'` em ambos os ambientes e postar o campo `engine`de cada um?

Comment: Outra coisa, consegue rodar a consulta `SELECT count(tema_id) FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas WHERE opt_aplicavel IS NULL` em ambos os ambientes e ver se eles retornam a mesma coisa?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly rodei o `show tables .. ` e o `engine` aparece nos dois como `NULL` e ao rodar q query para retornar o total de tema_id deu a mesma coisa.

Comment: Tenta `SHOW CREATE TABLE vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas;`, deve aparece a engine no final do comando retornado.

Comment: Nos dois deu a mesma coisa, `character_set_client = utf8` e `collation_connection = utf8_general_ci` .  Só lembrando que essa ai é uma view que tenho no banco.

Comment: faz um backup dessas tabelas/registros e disponibiliza em algum lugar que eu faço os testes no meu MySql e MariaDB p/ ver se fica igual ou diferente, até onde sei não é p/ existir diferença de Mysql->Maria, mas pode ter diferença de Maria->Mysql, ( tudo que tem no Mysql obrigatoriamente roda igual no Maria, mas nem tudo do Maria roda no Mysql )

Comment: @SneepSNinjA criei um arquivo com a criação das tabelas e a view necessário com os dados que precisa, segue o link https://gist.github.com/marcelod/91836c31cf4bdce5eadc

Comment: @MarceloDiniz testei com o que você passou ai no link, apesar de mostrar uma pequena diferença em comparação ao que você postou, os resultados obtidos tanto em MySql e em MariaDB são os mesmos

Comment: Exatamente isso que não estou entendendo. Já fiz de tudo, desde remover a base de dados e criar novamente e ainda assim na hospedagem que é onde esta instalado o MariaDB não me retorna o resultado correto.

Answer (score 13):

### Incompatibilidades entre *MariaDB* 5.1 e *MySQL* 5.1

Em alguns poucos casos *MariaDB* tem que ser incompatível para permitir *MariaDB* para fornecer mais e melhor informação do que *MySQL*.

Aqui está a lista de todas as incompatibilidades conhecidas nível de usuário que pode ter ao usar *MariaDB* 5.1 em vez do *MySQL* 5.1.

1. Os nomes dos pacotes de instalação começar com *MariaDB* em vez do *MySQL*.
2. Os tempos podem ser diferentes como *MariaDB* é, em muitos casos, mais rápido do que o *MySQL*.
3. *MySQLd* em *MariaDB* também lê as seções [*MariaDB*] de seus arquivos my.cnf.
4. Você não pode usar uma biblioteca de mecanismo de armazenamento única binário com *MariaDB* se ele não está compilado para exatamente a mesma versão *MariaDB*. (Isso ocorre porque o servidor interno estrutura THD é diferente entre *MySQL* e *MariaDB*. Isso é comum também entre as diferentes versões do *MySQL*). Isso não deve ser um problema, pois a maioria das pessoas não carregar novos mecanismos de armazenamento e *MariaDB* vem com mais mecanismos de armazenamento do que o *MySQL*.
5. `CHECKSUM TABLE`  pode dar resultado diferente como *MariaDB* não ignora NULL nas colunas de como *MySQL* 5.1 faz (versões futuras do *MySQL* deve calcular as somas de verificação da mesma forma que *MariaDB*). Você pode obter a soma de verificação "velho estilo" em *MariaDB* iniciando o *MySQLd* com a opção `--`. Note no entanto que o que *MyISAM* e mecanismos de armazenamento Aria em *MariaDB* estiver usando o novo verificação internamente, por isso, se você estiver usando `--old`, o comando `CHECKSUM` será mais lento, uma vez que precisa para calcular a soma de verificação de linha por linha.
6. O log de consultas lentas tem mais informações sobre a consulta, o que pode ser um problema se você tiver um script que analisa o log de consultas lentas.
7. *MariaDB*, por padrão, leva um pouco mais memória do que o *MySQL* porque temos ativado por padrão o mecanismo de armazenamento Aria para a manipulação de tabelas temporárias internas. Se você precisar de *MariaDB* tomar muito pouca memória (à custa de desempenho), você pode definir o valor de `aria_pagecache_buffer_size` a 1M (o padrão é de 128M).
8. Se você estiver usando novas opções de comando, novos recursos do *MariaDB* ou novos mecanismos de armazenamento, você não pode mover-se facilmente e para trás entre *MySQL* e *MariaDB*.

Fonte: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

Cara, parece que as diferenças vão começar a aparecer agora, mas os mais antigos não tem muita diferença não.

Comment: @CharlesS.Ferreira agradeço mesmo pela resposta, mas toda essa parte tem mais a ver com as versões 5.1, mas estou olhando no link que passou e lá tem algumas coisas em relação ao 5.5, não que essas não sirvam, mas acho que é algo mais especifico mesmo. Estou analisando ainda essas coisas! Valew

Answer (score 4):

Conforme testes obtidos com os mesmos registros e mesmas tabelas mostram que os resultados são os mesmos:

**Em MariaDB:**

```
     MariaDB [test]> SELECT DISTINCT umr.tema_id,    (        SELECT count(vw1.tema_id)        FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas vw1        WHERE ((vw1.tema_id = umr.tema_id)        AND (vw1.u
nidade_id = 68)        AND (vw1.opt_aplicavel = 1)        AND (vw1.opt_conforme = 1)        AND (vw1.dt_validate >= '2015-07-22'))    ) as conforme,    (        SELECT count(vw2.tema_id)        F
ROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas vw2        WHERE ((vw2.tema_id = umr.tema_id)        AND (vw2.unidade_id = 68)        AND (vw2.opt_aplicavel IS NULL))    ) as naoAvaliado,    (        SE
LECT count(vw3.tema_id)        FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas vw3        WHERE ((vw3.tema_id = umr.tema_id)        AND (vw3.unidade_id = 68)        AND (vw3.opt_aplicavel = 1 OR vw3.op
t_aplicavel IS NULL))    ) as totalAtribuido FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas umr WHERE (umr.unidade_id = 68 AND (umr.opt_aplicavel = 1 OR umr.opt_aplicavel IS NULL));
+---------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| tema_id | conforme | naoAvaliado | totalAtribuido |
+---------+----------+-------------+----------------+
|      20 |        2 |           0 |              2 |
|      21 |        3 |          18 |             24 |
|      11 |        8 |          19 |             29 |
|      24 |        1 |           0 |              1 |
|      18 |        1 |           0 |              1 |
|      23 |        0 |           2 |              2 |
|       7 |        0 |           0 |              2 |
|       4 |        0 |           2 |              4 |
|       2 |        1 |           0 |              1 |
+---------+----------+-------------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

**EM MySql:**

```
    mysql> SELECT DISTINCT umr.tema_id,    (        SELECT count(vw1.tema_id)        FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas vw1        WHERE ((vw1.tema_id = umr.tema_id)        AND (vw1.unidade_id
 = 68)        AND (vw1.opt_aplicavel = 1)        AND (vw1.opt_conforme = 1)        AND (vw1.dt_validate >= '2015-07-22'))    ) as conforme,    (        SELECT count(vw2.tema_id)        FROM vw_un
idades_monitoramentos_respostas vw2        WHERE ((vw2.tema_id = umr.tema_id)        AND (vw2.unidade_id = 68)        AND (vw2.opt_aplicavel IS NULL))    ) as naoAvaliado,    (        SELECT coun
t(vw3.tema_id)        FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas vw3        WHERE ((vw3.tema_id = umr.tema_id)        AND (vw3.unidade_id = 68)        AND (vw3.opt_aplicavel = 1 OR vw3.opt_aplicav
el IS NULL))    ) as totalAtribuido FROM vw_unidades_monitoramentos_respostas umr WHERE (umr.unidade_id = 68 AND (umr.opt_aplicavel = 1 OR umr.opt_aplicavel IS NULL));
+---------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| tema_id | conforme | naoAvaliado | totalAtribuido |
+---------+----------+-------------+----------------+
|      20 |        2 |           0 |              2 |
|      21 |        3 |          18 |             24 |
|      11 |        8 |          19 |             29 |
|      24 |        1 |           0 |              1 |
|      18 |        1 |           0 |              1 |
|      23 |        0 |           2 |              2 |
|       7 |        0 |           0 |              2 |
|       4 |        0 |           2 |              4 |
|       2 |        1 |           0 |              1 |
+---------+----------+-------------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.15 sec)

mysql>
```

**OBS: Dados obtidos através do link https://gist.github.com/marcelod/91836c31cf4bdce5eadc#file-database-sql**

Até onde se fala em diferenças entre esses bancos de dados, é simples lembrar da seguinte regrinha, o Mysql tem por obrigação entregar tudo o que for implementado para o MariaDB copiar (em sua versão free), o MariaDB vai manter a compatibilidade, porém poderá fazer melhor ou implementar algo novo, que por sua vez pode ser que no MySql não rode nestes casos.

Comment: Obrigado pelos testes, mas como me explica os resultados que mostrei, que também fiz com os mesmos dados? Será que pode ser problema na hospedagem?

Comment: Onde esta o erro no seu ambiente fica dificil de saber, se for possível fazer o seguinte, faz backup de um e dropa tudo no outro, depois restaura o backup e rode os mesmos sql em ambos, tem que dar os mesmos resultados

Comment: E garanta que ninguém esteja alterando/inserindo nas bases de dados enquanto testa

Comment: Já fiz esses testes e ainda assim continuam os mesmos resultados. Não sei mais o que fazer quanto a isso. Só para saber, qual versão do MariaDB que vc rodou?

Comment: as versões que usei foram Mysql 5.6.25 e MariaDB 5.5.45

Comment: As versões não irão mudar os resultados, o que pode acontecer entre as diferenças de versões é referente a recursos e performance, os resultados obtidos serão os mesmos,