# Resultados diferentes para query Mysql 5.1 e 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin, innodb

Desenvolvemos um projeto para um cliente utilizando MySQL 5.1.68 e no momento da publicação identificamos que a hospedagem do cliente possuía a versão 5.7.4.

Depois de publicado o projeto, começamos a verificar alguns comportamentos estranhos nos resultados retornados na aplicação no servidor do cliente e como não estamos utilizando nenhum recurso "avançado" no banco, começamos a debugar as queries e chegamos à uma situação no mínimo estranha, a versão 5.7 retorna um resultado diferente da versão 5.1.

Identificamos o problema na query abaixo mas não conseguimos entender o porque. A subquery que retorna o quantidade `SELECT SUM(te1.quantidade) .... te2.id_atributo_valor = tb.id_atributo_valor` no 5.1 retorna 4, informação correta. Enquanto no 5.7 retorna `NULL`. Mas alterando `te1.id_produto = p.id_produto` por `te1.id_produto = e.id_produto` o valor retornando passa a ser 4, sendo que o `p.id_produto` e o `e.id_produto` fazem parte de um INNER JOIN da consulta ou seja tem o mesmo valor.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.id_estoque,
    tb.id_atributo_valor,
    p.id_produto,
    (
        SELECT SUM(te1.quantidade) 
        FROM produtos_estoque te1 
        INNER JOIN estoque_valores_atributo te2 ON te1.id_estoque = te2.id_estoque 
        WHERE te1.id_produto = p.id_produto AND te2.id_atributo_valor = tb.id_atributo_valor
    ) quantidade
FROM
    produtos p
        INNER JOIN
    produtos_estoque e ON p.id_produto = e.id_produto
        LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT t1.id_atributo_valor, t1.id_atributo, t2.separar, t0.id_estoque, t3.thumb 
        FROM produtos_estoque t
        INNER JOIN estoque_valores_atributo t0 ON t.id_estoque = t0.id_estoque
        INNER JOIN atributos_valores t1 ON t0.id_atributo_valor = t1.id_atributo_valor
        INNER JOIN atributos t2 ON t1.id_atributo = t2.id_atributo AND separar = 1
        LEFT JOIN produtos_estoque_fotos t3 ON t1.id_atributo_valor = t3.id_atributo_valor AND t3.principal = 1 AND t.id_produto = t3.id_produto
    ) tb ON e.id_estoque = tb.id_estoque
WHERE
    p.excluido = '0'
        AND p.id_produto = '157'
        AND e.inativo = '0'
        AND e.valor != '0.00'
        AND ((tb.separar = 1 AND tb.thumb IS NOT NULL) OR tb.separar IS NULL)
GROUP BY tb.id_atributo_valor , tb.separar = 1 , p.id_produto
ORDER BY p.id_produto DESC
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar ocorrendo? Há algum parâmetro do 5.7 que deve ser ativado/desativado para que o comportamento seja semelhante nas 2 versões? A nossa preocupação é que exista mais alguma divergência dessa em outras consultas da aplicação.

OBS.: Essa query é utilizada tanto na tela de apresentação de detalhes do produto (com o `p.id_produto` no WHERE) quanto na lista de produtos (sem o `p.id_produto`) e neste caso, sem o `id_produto` a quantidade é retornada corretamente.

Comment: Cara já teve uma pergunta muito parecida com essa, me falando que o MariaDB e MySql davam resultados diferentes, pedi p/ me mandar um dump( backup ) e rodei nos dois e deu o mesmo resultado, então minha dica é criar uma database de teste nas duas versões, restaurar o mesmo backup nas duas e rodar o mesmo SQL nas duas, se der diferença pode upar o arquivo na net que eu mesmo testo aqui p/ você

Comment: Da uma lida na minha resposta aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80141/12032

Comment: possível duplicata de [Diferença de resultado entre MySql 5.5 e MariaDB 5.5](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72171/diferen%c3%a7a-de-resultado-entre-mysql-5-5-e-mariadb-5-5)